# Why do i get broken image icon even if i set content-type="image/jpeg"?

Tags: php, html, image, http-headers

That question might look silly but i would appreciate if i get a good answer.
I know what http header is and we can change it using `header` function in php.
Suppose i have a php file `an_image.php` and the code of it is as below :

```
<?php header('Content-type:image/jpeg'); ?>
<img src="image/flower.jpg">
```

Why am i getting a broken icon? By changing the `header` content type am i not changing the output as image?

As i think `img` tag is still an `html` output so as i'm trying to set an `html` content into an image content so i get the broken icon.

So what is the use of content-type:image/jpeg and where can it be used?
For example `flower.jpg` picture is in my image folder. If i create `flower.php` 
and open the `flower.jpg` using a text editor and copy the code of it and paste it on `flower.php` and set the `heade`r `content-type:image/jpeg` and try to open it on browser it doesn't work saying syntax error.

Looking for a good explanation .

Answer (score 2):

The correct content type for what you're outputting is `text/html`. You'd use the `image/jpeg` content type only if you were outputting the actual image file's contents itself.

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
readfile('image/flower.jpg');
```

Common uses include having a PHP script output a protected file after verifying a user's permissions allow it to be accessed, tracking pixels (save some data then serve a 1x1 image, for example), and serving dynamically generated images.